# Check if Entity is exists in deeply related Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core, relationship

I am trying to check wether an Entity exists in a deeply related Entity. Here is an picture of my model and the code I am using for the relationships.

**Image**
[image: ![enter image description here]

**Code**

```cs
public class TimeTable
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TimeTableId { get; set; }

    public TimeTableType TimeTableType { get; set; }
    // one to many relation with TrainSeries
    public List<TrainSerie> TrainSeries { get; set; } = new List<TrainSerie>();

}

public enum TimeTableType
{
    Type1,
    Type2
}

public class TrainSerie
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TrainSerieId { get; set; }

    // one to many with Train
    public List<Train> Trains { get; set; } = new List<Train>();

    // Many to one with TimeTable
    public Guid TimeTableId { get; set; }
    public TimeTable TimeTable { get; set; }
}

public class Train
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TrainId { get; set; }

    public TrainType TrainType { get; set; }

    // one to many with TrainActivity
    public List<TrainActivity> TrainActivities { get; set; } = new List<TrainActivity>();

    // many to one with TrainSeries
    public Guid TrainSerieId { get; set; }
    public TrainSerie TrainSerie { get; set; }
}

public class TrainActivity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TrainActivityId { get; set; }

    public ActivityType Act`enter code here`ivityType { get; set; }

    // many to one with TrainStation
    public Guid TrainStationId { get; set; }
    public TrainStation TrainStation { get; set; }

    // many to one with Train
    public Guid TrainId { get; set; }
    public Train Train { get; set; }

}
```

I have a list of TrainActivities and for each TrainActivity I want to check if the TrainActivity exists in a TimeTable object with TimeTableType==Type1. If so, I want to keep the TrainActivity in the list else I want to remove it from the list.

What is the easiest way to do this? I can't do this:

trainActivity.Train.TrainSerie.TimeTable.TimeTableType == TimeTableType.Type1

Because each reference navigation property is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what database you use and how you keep the enum in the table property TimeTable.TimeTableType, but if you change it to string you can try something like this

```
public class TimeTable
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TimeTableId { get; set; }

    public string TimeTableType { get; set; }
    // one to many relation with TrainSeries
    public List<TrainSerie> TrainSeries { get; set; } = new List<TrainSerie>();

}

//result will be a list of TrainActivities with all properties loaded and only with TimeTableType = Type1
var result = dBcontext.TrainActivities
                .Include(x => x.Train)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.TrainSerie)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.TimeTable)
                .Where(x => x.Train.TrainSerie.TimeTable.TimeTableType == "Type1")
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it also possible to check from the TrainActivity propety wether it has a relationship with a TimeTable with TimeTableType1 ( Something like this: trainActivity.Train.TrainSerie.TimeTable.TimeTableType == Type1)? Currently my  reference navigation properties are null. When I try to assign a value to those propeties I get a primairy key constraint.

Comment: How you keep enum in the database ?

Comment: What data type is your TimeTableType column in TimeTable table ?

Comment: I have fixed the problem, Thanks for your help!